# jspdf Expected : error for get width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, canvasjs

I've been facing this issue from the past two days where in the html code is throwing an error for "Expected :". I'm basically using canvasjs along with jspdf and on load of the page I get that error. I replace my local copy with the cdn link thinking that the issue would get resolved, but it still didn't get solved.

Error that is coming:

Expected ':' 
jspdf.debug.js, line 1023 character 9

The error is occurring the main file for jspdf hence I can't proceed further. The following code is writting the the above mentioned line:

```
        'pageSize' : {
            get width() {            //<<<<<<this line is causing the error
                return pageWidth
            },
            get height() {           //<<<<<<I'm assuming this line will also causing an error
                return pageHeight
            }
        },
```

The same code is found at the CDN link. The CDN link is as follows: 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.1.135/jspdf.debug.js

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have faced this issue, this seems to be an issue with the IE version and chrome version that you are using. I was using IE 8 which doesn't support JSPDF hence I was getting that error in IE. The same error was coming on Chrome version: 17.0.963.83. Updated Chrome as well now. Now everything is working fine!